# Robot Framework: Get user test, No keyword with name 'get' found. Did you mean: BuiltIn.Get Time

Tags: api, robotframework

I try to run my testing but it doesn't work.
here my code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     RequestsLibrary
Library     Collections
Library     JSONLibrary

*** Variables ***
${base_url}         https://reqres.in

*** Test Cases ***
Get user test
    Run Keywords
    [Tags]    get
    ${resp}=    get   ${base_url}/api/users/2
    Status Should Be    OK    ${resp}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
```

and there's always a sign that "no keyword with name ____ found"

Comment: When you run the test, did you look to see if robot reported on stdout that it couldn't import RequestsLibrary? You will get this error if the library failed to load.